# Why is my code wrong? about tensorflow, error code: value error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

For the first time, I try to code machine learning code.
However, I faced a problem

But I don't know what is the problem and how can I fix it.
Please answer it.

below is my code.

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(np.array(padded_smishing).shape[1], ), dtype='float32')
embedded_sequences = Embedding(Vocab_size, max_len, input_length=max_len, mask_zero= True)(sequence_input)

lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, dropout=0.5, return_sequences = True))(embedded_sequences)
lstm, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = Bidirectional \
  (LSTM(64, dropout=0.5, return_sequences=True, return_state=True))(lstm)

state_h = Concatenate()([forward_h, backward_h]) # 은닉 상태
state_c = Concatenate()([forward_c, backward_c]) # 셀 상태
attention = BahdanauAttention(64) # 가중치 크기 정의
context_vector, attention_weights = attention(lstm, state_h)

z_s = WeightedSum()([embedded_sequences, attention_weights])
p_t = Dense(128)(z_s)
p_t = Activation('softmax')(p_t)
r_s =WeightedAspectEmb(128, 128, W_constraint=MaxNorm(10), W_regularizer=ortho_reg)(tf.convert_to_tensor(p_t))

model = Model(inputs=sequence_input, outputs = r_s)

mypotim = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001, beta_1 =0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer=mypotim,loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

error code is here

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-170-d2314a49eedb> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=24, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), callbacks=callbacks)

    ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created on the first call. Make sure the tf.Variable is only created once or created outside tf.function. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables for more information.
```

Comment: did you read the referenced documentation at [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. It's my first time, so I can't tell you guys what is wrong. Sorry. I'll practice more. thank you

Comment: Please share the entire reproducible code (if it is shareable) which will be helpful for us to understand the issue and fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the function decorator is being used in the TF2.0 version for which the `run function eagerly` needs to be enabled after importing TensorFlow as :

`tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)`

However the above mentioned function is deprecated hence the below one needs to be used -

`tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`

You can refer to this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/run_functions_eagerly) for more information.